# Rails Mailer :from not totally working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, gmail

The address I am using with a mailer's `:from` is NOT showing up in sent emails. It is using the email address associated with the smtp_settings (gmail address) in the config.

I can set the name of the sender using "Name ", but the email address gets changed upon message receipt.

Everything looks as it should in the logs, but not when the email shows up.

Any ideas?

Comment: More information needed. Can you show the full outgoing e-mail headers from the Rails log, then show the full headers on the recipient end also. Note that GMail might not allow putting in bogus "From" fields. At minimum GMail will insert a `Sender` field in the headers identifying the account being used. Depending on the mail client the `Sender` might be shown on the receving end instead of the `From` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment, I think this should explain what is happening and why:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14464/spoof-sender-through-gmail-smtp-in-thunderbird

But like I said, if you debug the headers on both the sending and receiving end, you should be able to discover if something is changing something along the way (in this case it looks like GMail will patch the headers if you use an unverified `From`).